# Creating bubble plot for metaprop

Tags: r

I was trying to plot a metaregression for proportions using the `meta` package. The metaregression using `metaprop` works as expected. But when I run `bubble`, I get the error listed below the script:

```
library(meta)  
sample <- c(74, 62,370, 72, 40, 84, 290, 244, 173, 106, 89, 139, 43, 398, 179, 31)  
BLIPS <- c(23, 12, 11, 11, 1, 17, 52, 28, 6, 4, 3, 4, 1, 56, 22, 1)  
covar <- c(21, 11, 14, 1, 4, 47, 2, 42, 16, 44, 3, 34, 11, 15, 21, 4)  
hr <- data.frame(sample, BLIPS, covar)  
meta <- metaprop(BLIPS, sample)  
reg <- metareg(meta, covar)  
reg  
bubble(reg)
```

> Error in `[.data.frame`(x$.meta$x$data, , covar.name) :    undefined
>   columns selected

Comment: Welcome to SO. I have added some more explanation, so it is easier to locate the error and have formatted your code slightly, so it becomes easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Currently your metaregression uses the variables from the global environment and not the variables from your `data.frame` hr. This appears to work as for the regression itself, but not for the bubble plot. If you just add `data = hr` to your `metaprop` call, then the bubble plot works as expected.

```
hr <- data.frame(sample, BLIPS, covar)  
meta <- metaprop(BLIPS, sample, data = hr)  
reg <- metareg(meta, covar)  
reg
bubble(reg)
```